# Force DirectX 9 system-wide (NVidia-Windows7)

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, directx

The question is simple and guess it's popular amongst gamers.

My card supports DX11 but it's really slow when a game tries to use DX11 stuff.

Now.. I have 4+gigs of ram and a modern CPU.
(GPU: NVidia GTX 260 , so we are talking about NVidia here.)
I just want to play games with a playable framerate.

Is it possible to FORCE games to DX9? Like telling them I have only DX9 and they can't even touch DX10-11?

It'd be awesome since I just don't want to go back to XP. (And with this much memory, I'm doomed anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on which game you're talking about. Most have DX9 fallback renderers, which can be specified by Command line options/config files/ game settings.

Having said that, GTX260 isn't exactly a slow card, I'd recommend you tone down AF/AA settings first and then think about forcing DX9. DX11 isn't much of a performance guzzler.

Oh BTW: GTX 260 does **not** support DirectX 11

Comment: hmmm. So there is no way to force them ? So like.. say we have XP instead of Win 7 ?:)

Comment: no, AFAIK, there's no way to force it. You could have a look at driver settings. if you have XP then the DX10/DX11 exclusive game won't run.